# How to modify PDF values inside the Properties box under File menu when generating PDF with wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf

After creating a pdf file with wkhtmltopdf lib, if you go under File->Propertes tab, you notice that there are some values that are generated by wkhtmltopdf. However, I would like to modify or remove some of these. Does anyone have any experience with this? I would like to either modify "Producer" property or get rid of it completely.

Has anyone been able to succeed in this? I google'd this question and no answer came up. I also went through the manual, and there is no command that really helps with any of these details.

If you have a way to make these changes I would greatly appreciate the answer you give to this question in advance.

Thanks,

-e